# Outlook 2010 Tasks Percentage complete column

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks

Is it possible to have the percentage complete column show as progress bars or even as a little Gantt chart?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Expand right pane until you can see the column titles. Then right click on the titles and select Field Choose. Drag % complete onto the Tasks.

However, it only appears when the task bar is of a certain width, regardless of how many columns are visible.

So, what you can do is group by % which may be OK. Right click in the pane and select view settings. Then click Group By and select % Complete. You can select multiple Group By so you can still have the due date first, and then % complete as a subset.